# phpMyAdmin cannot process foreign keys and enforce foreign key constraints within my database

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have encountered issue with the phpMyAdmin installation on my live server. It appears that the phpMyAdmin version I am currently using is unable to process foreign keys and enforce foreign key constraints within my database.

Here are the relevant details regarding the phpMyAdmin installation:

- phpMyAdmin Version: 5.2.1
- Server Environment: Web server
- MySQL/MariaDB Version: 10.3.39-MariaDB-cll-lve - MariaDB Server
- Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.1.16
- PHP version: 8.1.16

The problem I am facing is that whenever I try to create a foreign key relationship between tables or apply foreign key constraints to existing tables, the changes do not take effect. I have followed the appropriate steps to define the foreign key relationships using the phpMyAdmin interface, but the changes are not reflected in the database structure.

To troubleshoot the issue, I have performed the following steps:

- Verified that the database engine supports foreign keys and foreign key constraints. Based on my research, the engine in use (MySQL or MariaDB) should support these features.
- Double-checked the syntax and correctness of the foreign key definitions.

I have ensured that the referenced tables and columns are correct.

Tested the creation of foreign keys and foreign key constraints using direct SQL queries instead of relying on the phpMyAdmin interface. However, the results were the same - the changes did not take effect.

Considering the importance of foreign key relationships and constraints in maintaining data integrity and ensuring database consistency, this issue is of utmost concern to me. It hinders my ability to establish referential integrity between tables and enforce cascading updates and deletions.

Comment: Need to add table structure along with the SQL that didn't seem to work. There could simply be some syntax issues.